# Separate detailed time stamp in google sheets

Tags: date, google-sheets, time, string-formatting, number-formatting

I have a time indicator looking like this:
2002-01-01T05:00:31.217Z

I want to separate this in
day ("yyyy-mm-dd") and time("hh:mm:ss") in tzo different rows.

Command `=text(field, "yyyy-mm-dd")` does not work, it still displays 2002-01-01T05:00:31.217Z

The application is google sheets. How can I separate it correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(SPLIT(A2:A, "TZ", 1))
```

if you want to reformat it:

```
=INDEX(TEXT(SPLIT(A2:A, "TZ", 1), {"dd/mm/yyyy", "hh:mm:ss"}))
```